Is it possible to convert the first layer of the G-code to a 2D print so I can use a 2D printer for a quick size reference?
Is it possible to convert the first layer of the G-code to a 2D print so I can use a 2D printer for a quick size reference?
The G-code (or STL) already contains the exact sizes so I think it shouldn't be hard, yet I could not find any easy solution for this.
Like this, but in realistic size:

So since most 2D printers use standardized A4 paper and PDF can also use A4 standardized size. It would be very helpful for many 3D prints to have a tool that can quickly take a G-code and generate a PDF of the first layer so that I can use a 2D printer for a quick print size preview when printed in actual size.
This is helpful for example when comparing it to a physical object, and saves wasted filament and time by waiting for the first layer or the whole print to finish and to find out the size wasn't (exactly) right.

Ok, I just wrote my own program to achieve this. I might share it as I didn't find any other solutions for this simple task. I'm still interested in other possible solutions.

That sounds like an answer! Maybe share the code through GitHub in the answer, or provide some essential hints using techniques and (python) libraries?

I have a working CLI PoC and working GUI PoC. I'm less experienced in making GUI but that was another project of me, so I'll probably soon publish both cross-platform tools as CLI and GUI for MacOS, Linux, Windows. If I find time to finish this.

i just take a screenshot of the slicer interface looking directly down, and print it using an app where i can easily customize the printed image size (eg. photoshop).

This suggestion may be more convoluted than your solution, but one can use OpenSCAD to import an STL, use projection() to create a slice of the first layer of the desired thickness, then export it as an SVG.
Additionally, Prusa Slicer (among others) when configured for a resin printer will generate a series of .PNG files representing the layers to be sent to the printer to expose the resin. The resulting file will have a proprietary extension, but when changed to .ZIP, can have the individual layers extracted and the images processed in the desired manner. Still convoluted, less programming involved.
